# @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, datetime

I receive a JSON in string format which I'm converting to Java Object Class using the Gson library. In that JSON the DateTime field is annotated with  **@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")** The original format in which the date is **"creationDate": "2022-10-25T10:38:32.000+01:00"** after converting the JSON to Java Object Class the format of the DateTime fields changes to **Tue Oct 25 15:08:32 IST 2022** rather than converting it to the required format.
Below is an example of my POJO class

```
@Data
public class Root{
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date creationDate;}
```

Below is an example of how I'm converting my string to Java Object Class

```
String fileContent = Files.readString(Path.of"**Path of the file**"));
        Root root = new Gson().fromJson(fileContent, Root.class);
```

JSON example:

```
root{
"creationDate":"2022-10-25T10:38:32.000+01:00"
}
```

I dont understand why this is happening. I know I can convert it using new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(sDate1)
But I want to understand why @annotation is not working

Comment: Please stop using the outdated `java.util.Date` class, use the more modern `java.time` API

Comment: Date and such types aren't formatted types. The result of applying the formatter to one, which is a String, is the formatted value.

Comment: `2022-10-25T10:38:32.000+01:00`, that matches a modern `OffsetDateTime` perfectly. So use `OffsetDateTime` instead of the porly designed and long outdated `Date` class. And by all means avoid `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s even worse.

Comment: What do you mean by _"... the format of the DateTime fields changes to ... "_?  You're putting it in a `Date`, which doesn't actually have a format.

Comment: @OleV.V. I tried using OffsetDateTime. I worked up to some extent but I'm still not able to achieve the required pattern. Pattern received 2022-10-25T09:38:32Z required is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: *...rather than converting it to the required format* - what is the required format?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Jackson annotation over the date field to format date :-

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
```

Comment: When the format in JSON is `2022-10-25T10:38:32.000+01:00`? I doubt it.

Comment: This could be helpful -@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")

Answer (score 0):

`Date` (old obsolete style), `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` do not possess an inherent format.

Date's toString() as used in `System.out.println(new Date());` gives that format you saw.

"2022-10-25T10:38:32.000+01:00" is the ISO standard format, `T` signifying the start of the time part. It is the format of an `OffsetDateTime` which is still Locale (country) independent, and does not deal with daylight savings time. `ZonedDateTime` would be better.

```
OffsetDateTime t = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-10-25T10:38:32.000+01:00");
ZonedDateTime zt = t.toZonedDateTime(); // Default zone
Date d = Date.fromInstant(t.toInstant());
```

For other format variants you can use a `DateTimeFormatter`.